# If a set of functions contains a sequence that is Cauchy, but not convergent, what does that imply about the set or the functions?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, soft-question

This is not homework. I am studying a set $S$ of of distributions that all have a fixed mean and also satisfy some ancillary criteria.

---

Lets say I have a sequence of probability density functions $f_{b_n} \in S$ defined over a domain $x\in [0,b_n)$ such that if $X_n\sim f_{b_n}$ then $E_{f_{b_n}}[X_n]=\mu >0 ,\forall n\in \mathbb{N}$.

However, $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} f_{b_n} = \delta(0) \implies E_{\delta(0)}[X_{}]=0\neq \mu$.

If we define the set $S:=\{f_b:E[f_b]=\mu,x\geq0\}$, then is seems there exists a sequence of functions in $S$ whose limit is not in $S$.

I think I have reasoned the above correctly, but I don't know the practical importance of this observation. Does this mean that the distributions $f_b$ are pathological in some sense? Or does it simply mean that any random variable with this distribution must be bounded?

Comment: I am confused by your notation.  What exactly is the set $S$?  Is $x$ a point or a set?  What do you mean by saying a *set* is Cauchy (this usually applies to sequences)?  And most importantly, when you talk about a space being complete or not, you have to say what metric you are using.

Comment: @NateEldredge Hi Nate. Ill edit my most, but first I'll answer your questions and then ask a few: The set is a set of functions over the non-negative reals. $X_b$ is a random variable having distribution $b$ while $x$ is just a point in the domain of $f_b$. I think I mean to say that the set is incomplete because not all sequences are Cauchy. Finally, I am referring to pointwise convergence of the sequence of functions.

Comment: @NateEldredge I edited it based on yhour comments. I don't know if it needs to be a metric space, as I care about pointwise convergence, so its really just a set of functions parametized over $b$ which happens to not contain all limits of sequences of its members.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dear Bey being complete or non complete is not related to being Cauchy or not for sequences, but in complete sets the Cauchy sequences is convergent, that is there limit is also belong to that set. Your deduction from that assumption is not correct.

Comment: So in my case, I have a sequence of functions in my set that do not converge to a member of that set...what is that called and what does it imply. I apologize for my butchery of real analysis here, but I was trying to be precise in what my issue is

Comment: I think that you want to say you have a sequence that is Cauchy but not convergent. Let me know Do you mean?

Comment: Yep...that's it. The sequence does have a limit, but that limit is not a member of the set.

Comment: Exactly! I think that you can change the question.

Comment: Thanks Ali. I corrected my terminology. Please let me know if this property implies anything problematic with $f$ as a density function.

Comment: No! $f$ maybe not a density function. Yet $f$ maybe not function just point.